# (@aws-cdk/pipelines): slow pipelines

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-cdk

I have set up cross account deployment pipelines using cdk. Actually everything works as expected so I'm quite happy here.

BUT

The problem is with execution time. For my application it takes more or less 30 minutes to get the pipeline fully executed. I have circa 200 components with around 70 FileAssets.

I see several issues here:

- FileAssets jobs are executed simultaneously in a single stage - each in separate docker image. Even though these jobs are executed at the same time it's seems it's not optimal. I guess better would be to execute everything in a single job.
- when a single change is introduced in the repository everything is re-deployed again, so we get feedback after 30 minutes which is unacceptable for development cycle.

Anyone can recommend some good practices here? I'm using piplines cdk module.

Thanks

Comment: One thing we're running into is that even if we deploy a single stack, all stack's build.  When you have stacks that have a dozen lambdas, the one-by-one build of stack lambdas that you aren't deploying is like death by a thousand paper cuts.

Comment: In my case it's the application deployment time that's the worst. I've concluded that I need to create a separate pipeline dedicated for application deployments.  The problem with this approach is that I'll end up with race-conditions between the infrastructure pipeline and the application deployment pipeline. Haven't figured out how to solve that problem, yet.